# VSCode with ESLint extension doesn't work when access files via samba

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.5.3 on Windows 7 with ESLint extension 1.0.6 and access the files on a machine with Linux version 4.2.8 via samba share. The ESLint installed on the Linux machine works well. VSCode with ESLint extension works well on local files as well. But when I use VSCode to access the files on the Linux machine, it seems like the .eslintrc file was not loaded by the ESLint extension at all with no error message. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

ESLint works well on Linux console.
[image]

ESLint works well on Windows local.
[image]

.eslintrc on Windows local.
[image]

VSCode on Windows access the files on Linux. ESLint extension doesn't work.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @jessehouwing! It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the windows file share location directly (e.g. `\\linuxserver\share`), try mapping the file to a drive using `net use l: \\linuxserver\share` and then proceed from there using `l:` as the root for your project.